# See value of any variable at runtime in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I want to `see` any variable's value at `runtime` in `Android Studio`, I saw this post [is-it-possible-to-watch-variables-at-runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172967/is-it-possible-to-watch-variables-at-runtime) but in the answer, it is mentioned to set a `breakpoint` first and then see the value of the variable in the breakpoint.

But the thing is I want to add these breakpoints (variables whose values I want to see) at `runtime`, now is there any possible way I can do that.

Please help me, anyone.

Thanks

Comment: You can launch the program in a debug mode without any breakpoints at first, navigate through it and then at any point add a breakpoint while the program is running. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @LieForBananas exactly

Comment: But you can do it. For example, just now I launched a program without any breakpoints, then I decided to put a breakpoint in my `onClick` method, I put the breakpoint, then without relaunching  the app I click on the button and it stops in a debug mode, after that if you are done you just press F9 and the execution continues, then you can put another one somewhere else and repeat.

Comment: @LieForBananas Thanks Yeah it's working but just one more question, after closing the app why debugger is getting removed I still want to debug and see the data inside the variables?

Comment: @LieForBananas I mean I still want to debug and see the data inside the variables after `opening my app again`?

Comment: I believe because the process associated with the debugger, which is your app is stopped or paused so it detaches. If it's not too much trouble than you can relaunch your app in a debug mode again, or another form of debugging is just put `Log` statements all over the place :) but I am sure you already know that.

Comment: @LieForBananas Yeah but at the runtime, I want to do everything so adding Logs will not work at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, but AFAIK the debugger will always detach if you close the app.

Comment: @LieForBananas Got the solution see the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17677506/android-studio-open-debug-mode-when-app-is-running Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Oh! Thanks for sharing :) Never knew that :) Good luck!